# why are nodes not being reassigned to new term when termid is changed?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, database

I'm having to create new taxonomies for a client and they want nodes that are associated with these terms and taxonomies to be assigned to the new taxonomy, I have done this via MySQL with an update statement so that all nodes associated with a certain term are now associated with the new one e.g.

```
UPDATE taxonomy_copy
SET tid = 316
WHERE tid = 152
```

Now when I do my select * query it shows all the nodes are associated with the new taxonomy but when I check the front end the node is still associated with the previous taxonomy, I've cleared cache and history and this still doesn't help.

Any Ideas how to resolve this issue??

Comment: There's no `taxonomy_copy` table in Drupal, do you mean `taxonomy_index`?

Comment: I second that. Also, why don't you rename the old taxo to it's new name. In that way you won't need to go dirty on the back end?